# jQuery get each background image URL of each element and wrap it in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So i am trying to get the background-image url of each div that has the class "client" in it. From there I want put that URL into an a href and wrap around another element so i can make it pop in a light box.

I've gotten this far but it only seems to grab the first url and then applies it to all of the elements.

```
// Make client rotator pop-up and get image url

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.client').each(function(index, el) {
   var bgurl =  $('.bg-cover').css('background-image');

    if(bgurl != 'none') {
        bgurl = bgurl.replace('url("','').replace('")','');
        jQuery('.client .flex_cell_inner').wrapInner('<a href="'+ bgurl +'" rel="lightbox"></a>');
    };
});
});
```

here is the URL to the site. go to our clients section in the homepage near the bottom: http://staging.idgadvertising.com/locationconnection/

Comment: Use $(this).find('.flex_cell_inner').wrapInner....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. If you're trying to get the background image of each item, you should use `$(this)` which references the current item in the loop (in this case, each `.client` div as you loop over them). The way you have it now is referencing a collection of every `.client` div on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bg-cover').each(function(index, el) {
    var bgurl = $(this).css('background-image');

    if (bgurl != 'none') {
      bgurl = bgurl.replace('url("','').replace('")','');
      $($('.client .flex_cell_inner')[index]).wrapInner('<a href="'+ bgurl +'" rel="lightbox"></a>');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: When you say the "first one" what exact div are you referencing? if you are certain you have more than one `.client` div on the page, the above code will definitely reference the different background urls for each `.client` div and store it in `bgurl`. That's how `$(this)` works.

Comment: Try putting `console.log(bgurl);` right underneath where you set it, and see if it prints out the proper ones

Comment: I see, you phrased your question wrong. If you are wanting the background of each `.bg-cover` then you need to use my code and change `$('.client')` to `$('.bg-cover')`

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: i just changed and i also changed the backgrounds of the other elements just to see if maybe that had to do anything with it and it still nothing.

Comment: since it's a loop don't i have to make it go back and loop it again?

Comment: The question I have is, if you're collecting multiple background URLs, why are you setting it on a single div? If you are wanting to collect multiple background urls and set them on multiple divs, you will need to loop through those new divs and assign the background image that associates with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164646/discussion-between-jgax87-and-tallboy).

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to do. I want to set each div with is prospective background (ie: client x has background x, client y has background y, client z has background z).

Comment: Ok, then add `[index]` like this: `$('.client .flex_cell_inner')[index]...`. That will find the corresponding index `.client` div.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[index].wrapInner is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=1:7)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?ver=1:2)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

Comment: Are you sure that there is the exact same number of `.client .flex_cell_inner` divs as there are `.bg-cover` divs? They have to match exactly or it won't work the way it's written

Comment: yes there are 5 client divs and each one having it's on bg-cover

Comment: Can you post the HTML

Comment: it's on my test site since i am running wordpress with it.

Comment: Sorry, try this:

Comment: `$($('.client .flex_cell_inner')[index])`

Answer (score 0):

the `bgurl` will be the same in each iteration, because it is always the same selector `.bg-cover` if there are many it will always take the first occurance, you say you want the background-image of the `.client` you can use $(this) to referrence the current element in iteration

```
var bgurl = $(this).css('background-image');
```

Comment: my mistake..i want the url of each bg-cover. I am guessing it's the same correct?